# Why doesn't `find / -name my_filename` display all existing occurences?

Tags: shell, find

Searching for an executable shell script `eCmd`, as root, `# find / -name eCmd` only yields one hit under `/cif/cif_xxx/`.

However, another file with the name 'eCmd' is also to be found under `/opt/cif/cif_xxx/`. Those 2 files are neither soft-linked nor on separate disk.

**Q:** How come the second file does not show up in the output of my find command ?

Comment: a symbolic link maybe `/opt/cifs` => `/cifs` ? will `ls -i eCmd` give same inode number ?

Comment: One of them may be a symlink. Use the -L option

Comment: I'm sorry, with `type -l` you will find symlinks.

Comment: can you post the output of `ls -lid /cif/cif_xxxx/eCmd /opt/cifs/cifs_xxxx/eCmd`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers. I figured out the 2 files are indeed hard linked with each other(share the same inode no#)

So,

```
Find / -name (filename)
```

will not list the other hard linked files scattered around the server

suggest using

```
Find / -samefile (filename)
```

to find the other hard-linked files.

Comment: As far as I can tell hard links are displayed by `find`. In fact when you think about it, all the names to an inode are equivalent, there is no "main" one, so `find` could not tell which one to display.